# Using *args in a function inside a function, with a tuple as argument, and i dont understand why the return was a sum

Tags: python, function, tuples, args

```
def f2 (x,y):
    return x + y

def double (f):
    
    def g (*args,**kwargs):
        
        return 2* f(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return g


g = double(f2)

print(g(1,3))
```

I have a few questions about this code like:

- Why if a delete the line `return g` and the line `g = double(f2)` i get and error saying the `g` in not defined, despite i defined `g` as a function inside `doubled` even i call the `print(g(1,3))`

Comment: `f2 ` is not declared so the interpreter cannot find it. I think you should look at decorators: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First answer

Your variable f2 is indeed not declared. I assume from the result that it's a simple sum:

```
def f2(*args):
    return sum(args)
# you could also do this:
# f2 = lambda *args: sum(args)
```

From now, calling :

```
g = doubler(f2) # > function
g(1,2) # > 6
```

... is effectively the same as :

```
doubler(f2)(1,2) # > 6
```

The `doubler` function will wrap the function passed as argument inside another function `g`, which is not the same as your other variable g.

Also, the `assert` will raise the exception with the custom string if the assertion is **false**, not true.

So your code should be made clearer, for educational purposes, like so:

```
def doubler (f):
 
     def g( *args, *kwargs):

         return 2 * f(*args, **kwargs)
 
     return g

def f2(*args):
    return sum(args)

doubled_f2 = doubler(f2)

assert doubled_f2(1,2) == 6, "doubler is **in**correct"
# or:
assert doubled_f2(1,2) != 6, "doubler is correct"
```

## Updated question

```
def f2 (x,y):
    return x + y


def doubler (f):

    def g (*args,**kwargs):
    
        return 2* f(*args, **kwargs)

    return g

g(1, 3)
# > NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

The reason of this exception has to do with scopes. `g` is defined inside a function. The scope of `g` is inside the function `doubler`, therefore you can't access it from outside the function `doubler`.

```
def a(): 
    return 1

def b():
    def a():
        return 2
    return a() 

# Accesses the function a() defined in the outer scope.
a()  # -> 1
# Accesses the function b() defined in the outer scope
# which will call the function a() defined in the inner scope.
b() # -> 2
```

Comment: i forget to declare the function f2 on the first time. Now i edited the question

Comment: I read your new answer. So i declare the `g` variable outside the function identation to be possible to call the g function outside the `doubler` identation? Because the `print(g(1,3))` gets me the correct answer

Comment: Your `print(g(1,3))` worked here because it's not overwritting the inner `g` function which is not reachable from the outer scope. It's confusing to use the same name for two different things though: your outer `g` function is the `f2` function wrapped inside another `g` function. They are two different functions anyways.